# How to cast the interval of DateDiff function of the SQL in to Datetime data type

Tags: sql, datediff

i have a query that uses DateDiff function of the SQL.The interval returns min, hour or days according to how i put it. I want to return a Datetime datatype instead of the resulting integer type as it does. I tried to cast it as follows .

```
 DATEDIFF(cast(MIN as datetime), b.FollowUpTime, a.FollowUpTime)
```

This returns an error. I also tried

```
DATEDIFF(Convert(datetime,convert(char(8),MiNUTE)), b.FollowUpTime, a.FollowUpTime)
```

It also returns wrong parameter error. Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: A `datetime` represents a fixed point on the timeline. Not an interval. These are logically different types of data. And if you're talking SQL Server, it doesn't have a datatype for representing an interval. `DATEDIFF` returns `int`s.

Comment: Thanks Damien. i understand and i am wondering if there is a way i can convert the "int s" so that its return as DD:HH:MM:SS, HH:MM:SS format instead of the traditional 'int s'

Comment: I am with @Damien_The_Unbeliever, but for your requirement, you can get the `DATEDIFF()` results `in Seconds` and calculate Days, Hours, Minutes and rest in seconds....

Comment: So, what you're really talking about is wanting to **format** the result of `DATEDIFF` into a *string* (`varchar`). Searching should find examples like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445600/datediff-in-hhmmss-format)

Comment: THanks Kaf. I understand i can get in second, but the calculation can you elaborate more may be by giving example. Is it after its return that the calculation is done or before the seconds are returned?

Comment: You have to get the number of seconds first and then calculate. Mindyou, `DD:HH:MM:SS` won't give a Datetime datatype as you say in the question title. It will be just a string. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to find the difference between two dates:

```
SELECT 
    convert(VARCHAR, abs(datediff(second, @date1, @date2) / 60 / 60 / 24)) 
    + ':' + 
    convert(VARCHAR, abs(((datediff(second, @date1, @date2) / 60) / 60) % 24)) 
    + ':' + 
    convert(VARCHAR, abs((datediff(second, @date1, @date2) / 60) % 60)) 
    + ':' + 
    convert(VARCHAR, abs((datediff(second, @date1, @date2) % 60)))
```

You'll just have to change the `@date1` and `@date2` with the dates you need.

Here is a [SQLFiddle where you can test this out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19287).

If you ***really want to convert to datetime***, use this:

```
SELECT 
    convert(DATETIME, 
        (convert(VARCHAR, abs(((datediff(second, @date1, @date2) / 60) / 60) % 24)) 
         + ':' + 
        convert(VARCHAR, abs((datediff(second, @date1, @date2) / 60) % 60)) 
         + ':' + 
        convert(VARCHAR, abs((datediff(second, @date1, @date2) % 60)))
           ) 
   + dateadd(day, 
             abs(datediff(second, @date1, @date2) / 60 / 60 / 24), 
             '01-01-1900 00:00:00')
             )
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle for the second query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19297)

Comment: i think there might be a little flaw in here, if you try to get the resulting string back into a datetime it returns `January, 01 1900 00:01:00+0000`; shouldn't it be `January, 01 1900 01:00:00+0000` ? got it in this slightly varied fiddle of yours http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19290

Comment: You want to convert a `TIME DIFFERENCE` to a `FIXED POINT` in time. It is not correct as Damien_The_Unbeliever commented previously.

Comment: I don't know how you can further use `January, 01 1900 01:00:00+0000` as the difference.

Comment: Well I did not say it is best practice, but you can indeed, you just have to keep in mind that you will have to subtract that "pseudo-difference" from `January, 01 1900 01:00:00+0000` each time you want to do some comparison.

Comment: True, that is the solution, but it would be a bit twisted. I don't think the OP is aware of how `datetime` formats information.

Comment: Thanks , the first convertion that returns 0:0:0:0 is what i need. thanks for the help.

Comment: @Radu .. Pls can you help check this question for me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479775/modalpopupextender-in-grigview-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments `DATEDIFF` returns an `INT` value of the difference of both dates.

Since `DATETIME` is based on 1900-01-01 being the "base date" meaning assinging 0 to a `DATETIME` will result in the value 1900-01-01, you can add your date difference to that and get a value relative to that point in time (1900-01-01).

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETUTCDATE())

DECLARE @zeroDate DATETIME = 0

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @date1, @date2), @zeroDate)
```

I also set up an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deb4e/5) where you can try that out.