# modalpopupextender in Gridview Not Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Somebody pls help. Recently discovered Modalpopupextender and want to use it in my gridview. I want to an edit link button in my gridview. The link button when click should popup the Modalpopupextender . My problem now is that, the Modalpopupextender does not popup when i click the link button. Below is my code.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Members.ascx.cs" Inherits="Debt.Members" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="pnContainer" runat="server" Height="420px" Width="700px">
<style type="text/css">  

             .ModalBackground  
            {  
                  background-color: Gray;  
                  filter: alpha(opacity=60);  
                  opacity: 0.6;  
                  z-index: 10000;  
            }  

            .ModalPopup  
            {  
                  background-color:White;  
                  border-width:3px;  
                  border-style:solid;  
                  border-color:Gray;  
                  padding:5px;  
                  width: 350px; 
                  height:210px; 
            }  


</style>  
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;WELCOME &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="623px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                    onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvContact" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="cid"   
                                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"   
                                CellPadding="3" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="Black"   
                                GridLines="Vertical">  
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                                 <Columns>  
                                    <asp:TemplateField>  
                                        <ItemTemplate>  
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLinkView" runat="server" onclick="btnLinkView_Click" Text="View"></asp:LinkButton>  

                                        </ItemTemplate>  
                                    </asp:TemplateField>  
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="cid" HeaderText="Client ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="regno" HeaderText="Reg No" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Client Name" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Client Address" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="state" HeaderText="State" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="website" HeaderText="Website" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
                                      <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />



                                </Columns>  
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />  
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddEdit" runat="server" style="display:none;">
   <asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "Label4" runat = "server" Text = "Customer Details" ></asp:Label>
   <br />
       <table align="center">
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Reg No"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegNo" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Client Name"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="City"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Website"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtWebsite" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" Width = "40px" MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>
           <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick = "return Hidepopup()"/>
           </td>
           <td>
           <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick = "Save" />
           </td>

           </tr>
       </table>
    </asp:Panel>

            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="pnlAddEdit_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnControl"   PopupControlID="pnlAddEdit" 
                BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" DropShadow="true" CancelControlID="btnClose">
            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Button ID="btnControl" runat="server" style="display:none" /> 

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />

</asp:Panel>
```

and my btnLinkView_Click methpod is.

```
  protected void btnLinkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {

                LinkButton btnLinkView = sender as LinkButton;

                GridViewRow gvContactRow = (GridViewRow)btnLinkView.NamingContainer;
                 ////.ReadOnly = true;
                txtRegNo.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
                txtName.Text =  gvContactRow.Cells[2].Text.Trim();
                txtAddress.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[3].Text.Trim();
                txtCity.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
                txtState.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[5].Text.Trim();
                txtWebsite.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[6].Text.Trim();
                txtPhone.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[7].Text.Trim();
                txtEmail.Text = gvContactRow.Cells[8].Text.Trim();

                pnlAddEdit_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
```

IT isn't popping up as expected. Thanks.

Comment: DynamicServicePath="" it should not be null should be given path here

Comment: Sorry to ask but where should the path point to? what should it be?

Comment: i also dont know,if u dont need it why dont u remove that

Comment: Yup i did removed as you pointed since, but nothing change. Not sure where i go wrong.?